# Client-Server Auction system. Console mode

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp, client-server

I'm using C# Sockets. I'm doing a **auction server** and client project. Console mode.
Actually I have 1 server running asynchronosly for multiple clients.

**MAIN PROBLEM: When 1 auction ends, server have to send message to the winner(if exists), seller, and loosers. I need a kind of a clock to trigger events.**

On the client I can send commands like:

- "register username password"
- "login username password"
- "credit xxx.xx"
- "create product min_price duration" -- creat 1 auction
- etc..

Now I'm having troubles with the logic of the auction system.

When the server read (command == "creat") it have to create the auction with respective info.
How can this be done? 1 thread for each auction?

**When the time end's the server have to repply to:**

- winner (product name, winner bid)
- loosers (product name, his last bid, winner bid)
- creator (if his product was sold)

I've thought:

1. server read the command "creat"
2. server creat a new thread for that auction
3. the thread have a timer that see (thread.timer == time_to_end)?
4. when the (thread.timer = time_to_end) send all the messages!

Is this pseudocode possible to perform?

Which classes I have to use?

Server Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using Server;
using System.IO;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static TcpClient _cashierClient = new TcpClient();
        private static Dictionary<string, User> loggedUsers = new Dictionary<string, User>(); // <username, User>
        private static Dictionary<string, int> loggedUsers2 = new Dictionary<string, int>(); // <IPEndPoint, ID>
        private static List<User> registeredUsers = new List<User>();
        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
        private static List<Socket> _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket
            (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            ConnectToCashier();
            SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ConnectToCashier()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Cashier...");
            _cashierClient.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 101);

            Stream stream = _cashierClient.GetStream();
            byte[] receivedBuf = new byte[1024];
            int rec = stream.Read(receivedBuf, 0, 1024);
            byte[] data = new byte[rec];
            Array.Copy(receivedBuf, data, rec);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
        }

        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 100)); //Bind any interfaces on port 100
            _serverSocket.Listen(5); // Max 5 em Lista de espera
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            _clientSockets.Add(socket);
            Console.WriteLine("Client " + socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " connected");
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
            byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);

            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
            Console.WriteLine(socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " sent: " + text);

            string response = string.Empty;
            string command = text.ToLower().Split()[0]; // "command word1 word2 word... wordX wordX+1"
            int words = text.Split().Count(); // count the number of words + command
            if (command == "get_time" && words == 1) // SERVER TIME
            {
                response = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            }
            else if (command == "register" && words == 3) // REGIST USER
            {
                string[] split = text.Split();
                if (userExists(split[1]))
                {
                    response = "'" + split[1] + "' already in use. Choose another username";
                }
                else
                {
                    newUser(split[1], split[2]); //split[1] = name, split[2] = password
                    response = "'" + split[1] + "' Successfully Registered";
                }
            }
            else if (command == "login" && words == 3) // LOG IN
            {
                string[] split = text.Split();

                if (!userExists(split[1]))// check for username
                {
                    response = "Invalid Username";
                }
                else if (!userExists(split[1], split[2])) // check for username and corresponding password
                {
                    response = "Wrong Password";
                }
                else if (loggedUsers.ContainsKey(split[1]) ||
                    loggedUsers2.ContainsKey(socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString())) //checks if user is on hashtree by the [KEY = username] or [KEY = IPAdress]
                {
                    int id;
                    if (loggedUsers2.TryGetValue(socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), out id)) // O cliente já está logado com alguma conta
                    {
                        User user = getUser(id);
                        response = "You're allready Logged In As '" + user.username + "'";
                    }
                    else
                    { // O cliente não está logged in e está a tentar entrar numa contra logada noutro computador
                        response = "Another Computer is currently logged onto this account";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " loged in");
                    response = "Successfully Logging In";
                    //User user = new User(split[1], split[2]);
                    User user = getUser(split[1], split[2]); //split[1] = name, split[2] = password
                    loggedUsers.Add(user.username, user);
                    loggedUsers2.Add(socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), user.ID);
                }
            }
            else if (command == "balance" && words == 1) // SHOW AVAILABLE CASH
            {
                if (loggedUsers2.ContainsKey(socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString())) // Verifica se está logado
                {
                    int userID = loggedUsers2[socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()];
                    byte[] dataToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("balance " + userID);
                    Stream stream = _cashierClient.GetStream();
                    stream.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);

                    byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
                    int rec = stream.Read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024);
                    byte[] dataReceived = new byte[rec];
                    Array.Copy(dataBuffer, dataReceived, rec);

                    response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataReceived);
                }
                else // Se não estiver logado...
                {
                    response = "You are not logged in";
                }
            }
            else if (command == "deposit" && words == 2)
            {
                if (loggedUsers2.ContainsKey(socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString())) // Verifica se está logado
                {
                    string[] split = text.Split();
                    split[1] = split[1].Replace(".", ","); // Se o user escrever ####.## altera para ####,##
                    decimal value;
                    if (Decimal.TryParse(split[1], out value)) // It's a decimal
                    {
                        if (value < 10) // Abaixo da quantia minima
                        {
                            response = "Minimum Deposit 10 EUROS";
                        }
                        else // Quantia aceitavel
                        {
                            int userID = loggedUsers2[socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()];
                            byte[] dataToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("deposit " + userID + " " + value);
                            Stream stream = _cashierClient.GetStream();
                            stream.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);

                            byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
                            int rec = stream.Read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024);
                            byte[] dataReceived = new byte[rec];
                            Array.Copy(dataBuffer, dataReceived, rec);

                            response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataReceived);
                        }
                    }
                    else // No it's not.
                    {
                        response = "Invalid Cash Format. Use 'deposit ####,##'";
                    }
                }
                else // Se não estiver logado...
                {
                    response = "You are not logged in";
                }
            }
            else // Comando inválido
            {
                response = "Invalid Request";
            }

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
            socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), socket);
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
        }

        private static User getUser(string username, string password)
        {
            foreach (User user in registeredUsers)
            {
                if (user.username == username && user.password == password)
                    return user;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static User getUser(int id)
        {
            foreach (User user in registeredUsers)
            {
                if (user.ID == id)
                    return user;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static bool userExists(string username, string password)
        {
            foreach (User user in registeredUsers)
            {
                if (user.username == username && user.password == password)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private static bool userExists(string username)
        {
            foreach (User user in registeredUsers)
            {
                if (user.username == username)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private static void newUser(string username, string password)
        {
            User user = new User(username, password);
            registeredUsers.Add(user); // adiciona à lista de user's registados

            int userID = user.ID;
            byte[] dataToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("register " + userID);
            Stream stream = _cashierClient.GetStream();
            stream.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
        }

        private static void SendCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Socket _clientSocket = new Socket
            (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Client";
            LoopConnect();
            SendLoop();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void SendLoop()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a request: ");
                string req = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
                _clientSocket.Send(buffer);

                byte[] receivedBuf = new byte[1024];
                int rec = _clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuf);
                byte[] data = new byte[rec];
                Array.Copy(receivedBuf, data, rec);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
            }
        }

        private static void LoopConnect()
        {
            int attempts = 0;
            while (!_clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    attempts++;
                    _clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 100);
                }
                catch (SocketException) {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection attempts: " + attempts.ToString());
                }
            }

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }
    }
}
```

On this print you can see the server running and the client. Cashier server isn't important for this question.

http://goo.gl/wQZdb

Comment: I think that the solution that I was needing is explained here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/461682/Client-Server-Event-Subscription-Techniques-in-Csh but I dont know how to implement one of that Event Subscription Techniques with my comand line program. So I choosed to create a notifications command and with that buyers and sellers can see the status of his auctions.

Answer (score 0):

The timer doesn't have to be in individual threads. Actually, the auction data does not to be in individual threads. You can create a data structure-Auctions (class Auction, Owner, Participant, Bids) for that and store that in the main thread. What you need is one dedicated thread that continually checks for the Auctions data structure (you can have this stored in a database or memory, whatever suits your needs) to get all auctions that has elapsed and send notifications to all auction participants (Owner and Participant).

Comment: Your suggestion sounds good.
But as I am not very experienced in multythreading:
Is it possible to put the thread sleeping while no active auctions and wake it up when there are ongoing auctions?

Comment: There has to be a (monitoring) thread to check if there are ongoing auctions. So no, there has to be one thread to check if there are ongoing options. About your lack of experience in multi-threading, this is a great exercise for you and opportunity to gain experience. Be sure to read resources on multi-threading/locks. Read on Observer  /Publisher-Subscriber design pattern as well as I think you can use these patterns for your design.